# Looped delegate method returning repeats (multithreading)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

So I'm trying to make an app that lists the times the ISS is scheduled to Pass over the user's location. It works more or less smoothly, with one hiccup.

What I expect: Around 5 different times listed in a UITableView

What I get: 5 times listed in a UITableView with randomly repeated values. Sometimes all 1 value, sometimes the last one is also the second and/or 3rd to last, sometimes 2 values repeat themselves, any number of incorrect combinations. A small portion of tests return correctly.

What bugs me most is that the wrong results are inconsistent, so I can't see a way to brute force a crude solution.

Relevant code:
First the network manager class/delegate

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

//Delegate for thread communication
protocol NetworkManagerDelegate: class {
  func didGetPass(lastPass: Bool, pass: Pass)
  //Flag last model object to limit tableview reloads
}

//Using struct as manager class is not going to change state
struct NetworkManager {
  weak var delegate: NetworkManagerDelegate?
  //Set a base URL as far along as possible, will finish with data passed from function
  let baseURL = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?"

  func getPasses(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    //complete URL
    let lat = coordinate.latitude
    let lon = coordinate.longitude
    let requestURL = URL(string: "\(baseURL)lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)")
    //begin task
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestURL!) { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print(error as Any)
        //Generic report on failure to connect
        print("Could not reach API")
      } else {
        do {
          //Get JSON from data to parse
          if let resultJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
            //Get list of passes from JSON
            let passes = resultJSON["response"] as! [[String: Int]]
            //Set default parameters for delegate method
            var testPass: Pass
            var lastPass = false
            //loop through passes
            for pass in passes {
              //determine if last pass
              if pass == passes.last! {
                lastPass = true
              }
              testPass = Pass()/*This seems terribly inefficient to me
               However, attempting to create the object outside the loop and simply modify it
               leads to the same exact object being passed multiple times to the main thread, so
               the tableview's cells are all identical.*/
              testPass.durationInSeconds = pass["duration"] ?? 0
              //Convert date to Date object and set to testPass
              testPass.riseTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (Double(pass["risetime"] ?? 0)))
              //Inform main thread via delegate
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.delegate?.didGetPass(lastPass: lastPass, pass: testPass)
              }
            }
          }
        } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }

}
```

And on the main thread:

```
extension TrackingController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return passes.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Get cell, pass default if nil
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "passCell") as? PassCell else {
      return PassCell()
    }
    //Retrieve data from passes, assign to labels
    let pass = passes[indexPath.row]
    cell.timeLabel.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: pass.riseTime))"
    cell.durationLabel.text = "Duration: \(pass.durationInSeconds) Seconds"
    return cell
  }

}
extension TrackingController: NetworkManagerDelegate {
  func didGetPass(lastPass: Bool, pass: Pass) {
    passes.append(pass)
    if lastPass { //reload only once api calls are done
      passList.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

That should be all code that triggers from the moment the Network Manager's one function is called. Can anyone explain this to me? I have manually checked the API, I should not be receiving duplicate outputs here.

Edit: I just tried changing `DispatchQueue.main.async` to `DispatchQueue.main.sync`, and while it seems to fix the issue my understanding of multithreading leads me to believe this defies the point of running the call on another thread. That said, my understanding of multithreading isn't very practical, so I'm open to correction on that or to better solutions to my problem.

Comment: I would put some debugging output in to see where the problem is occurring. Check what happens in the do loop, what gets passed to  didGetPass.

Comment: Just did that, printing `testPass.durationInSeconds` in the line before `didGetPass`. The results are both wrong and do not even match what shows in the table view.

Putting that same print statement before `DispatchQueue.main.async` prints them in the right order, however, so I'm certain it involves the timing of that async closure.

Comment: Could you explain why you're calling the delegate callback in a loop?
You could simply call your delegate with the passes object.

Comment: Kunal Shah, Are you suggesting I handle converting from [[String: Int]] to [Passes] on the main thread?

Comment: You should be doing this instead:

func didGetPasses(_ passes: Passes) {
    passes.append(passes);
    passList.reloadData();
}

And call self.delegate?.didGetPasses(passes) once the for loop is completed.

Comment: I just did something similar, instead of passing each item one at a time I made an array and just passed it to the main thread. I have had bad experiences with that in the past, but it seemed to work this time and allows me to keep the delegate method asynchronous since it's outside the loop now. So far it works

Comment: Ideally, on the main thread, you don't do anything with the data until the last object has been received. So, passing the whole array at one go is a better approach.

Comment: Yup, and I credited you in the answer I provided since you did not put an official answer yourself. Thank you very much.

Comment: To piggy back on Kunal Shah's response, you may want to get acquainted with completion blocks. You can pass the result back to other functions upon completion and have more control of what happens and when.

Comment: @JoeyNash I'm trying to build my reputation on StackOverflow! So I'd appreciate it if you would upvote the answer I have just put up. 

Glad I could help!

Comment: @Jake Yeah, I've used those for making multiple/nested API calls since then I have extra threads branching from the original API call. But for just one network thread I thought it would be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, on the main thread, you don't do anything with the data until the last object has been received. So, passing the whole array in one go is a better approach.

You can do this instead:

```
func didGetPasses(_ passes: Passes) { 
    passes.append(passes); 
    passList.reloadData(); 
}
```

And call

```
self.delegate?.didGetPasses(passes)
```

once the for loop is completed.

PS: You should also consider using closures. It helps in handling logic and makes code more 'in-place' at the call site.

Comment: Thanks, I usually use escaping completion closures on nested API calls to ensure they come out in the right order. I just didn't think this situation called for it, seemed like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "passCell") as? PassCell else {
  return PassCell()
}
```

correct? seems you are returning an uninitialised PassCell there

Comment: Probably not, I just put that there to silence optional warnings. I'm not expecting a situation where dequeueReusableCell will return nil.

Answer (score 0):

I decided on an answer inspired by advice from Kunal Shah. I stopped looping the delegate call and instead put together a collection of Pass objects to send to the main thread.

I didn't want to do this as my previous experience with this led to empty collections being sent for some reason, but it seems to work here. This way I still only reload the tableview once, but also only call the delegate method once.